# Existence of a solution for geodesic differential equations for a singular metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics, differential-equations

In order to determine the geodesics, one must solve the following set of differential 
equations
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 x^j}{ds^2} + {j\brace h\,\,k}\frac{dx^h}{ds}\frac{dx^k}{ds} = 0,
\end{align}
where ${j\brace h\,\,k}$ is the Christoffel symbol of second kind, which is defined as
\begin{align*} 
{j\brace h\,\,k} = \frac{1}{2} g^{jk}\left[\frac{\partial g_{hk}}{\partial x^l} + 
                            \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^h} -
                               \frac{\partial g_{hl}}{\partial x^k}\right].
\end{align*}
Often, these equations can not be solved analytically, and we can only solve them 
numerically.

When solving the geodesic differential equations, **one of the main concerns seem to be the conjugate metric $g^{jk}$, and it's existence**. If the metric $g_{jk}$ is singular, i.e $det(g) = 0$, then the conjugate metric does not exist, as
\begin{align*}
g_{jk}g^{jk} = \delta_j^{\phantom{j}k}.
\end{align*}

My **questions** is as following :

Given an initial condition, does there still exist a geodesic that is a unique solution, or is it simply not possible to solve the equation?

Comment: 1. How is this a physics question? In which physical situation does $\det(g) = 0$ arise? 2. The notation ${j\brace h\,\,k}$ is horribly antiquated, why do you not use the more modern ${\Gamma^j}_{hk}$?

Comment: I like the curly braces, they remind me that the Christoffel symbols are not a tensorial quantity. Here is one author at least who still uses them : J. H. Heinbockel. Introduction to Tensor Calculus and Continuum Mechanics (2001). Thats actually the 21 century...oh gosh

Comment: Well, I'm not starting a war over this (i.e. I'm not editing your post, and I won't debate this further than this comment), but if you conceive of $\Gamma$ as an abstract connection form on the tangent bundle (explained e.g. [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Christoffel+symbols)), then ${\Gamma^j}_{hk}$ are indeed its components. The curly braces just intensify the idea that these objects are somehow "unnatural" and "don't transform right", when you just have to understand what geometrical object they actually belong to.

Comment: Bring it on! <rolls sleeves> No, I am just joking. But, as to your first point, it may be valid. As this is a question of existence and uniqueness, maybe mathoverflow is a better place to post it. But, in the end I just want answer(s), and perhaps some physical insight.

Comment: I do not understand the question. If $det(g)=0$, then $g^{ij}$ **does not exist** and the Christoffel symbol is not defined. In this sitiation there is no geodesical equation at all. Existence and uniqueness of what, if you do not have an equation?

Comment: So the equation it self is invalid for the singular case ?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The curly brace notation is used in e.g. Becker, Becker & Schwarz, *String Theory and M Theory.* This is a 2007 book, so not *that* antiquated.

Comment: In any case, a metric is defined as being nondegenerate, which means that the matrix representation has an empty kernel. This implies $\det g\ne0$.

Comment: Numerically it seems tricky though, as you can have matrices that are almost singular. But that is another issue.

Comment: $g^{ij}$ is the inverse matrix of $g_{ij}$. The inverse exists **if and only if** $det(g)\neq 0$. So, in the degenerate case, you cannot define the Christoffel symbol. Yes, the equation itself is not valid in the singular case.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/47883/13917

Comment: So someone had to do a Ph.D about it ?

Comment: Why all the votes to close? The question has a perfectly good answer i.e. that a singular metric is unphysical.